# how do i change volume of Clip that is playing in loop?

Tags: java, javasound

I am wrecking my brain on how to change the volume of a Clip that is already playing in loop mode.  The code I currently have is:

```
Clip c = currentSound.getClip();
FloatControl gainControl = 
    (FloatControl) c.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
gainControl.setValue(-10.0f);

currentSound.loop(loopCount);
```

Is my assumption that once the loop starts, the volume cannot be changed, true?

Comment: A looping clip's level is affected by master gain.  Let's have a look at your code that sets db.

Comment: Hello Java42,  dB was a constant in my try (-10.0f).  I have edited my code above.

Comment: To change the volume, simply make another call to gainControl.setValue(-80.0f) and the volume will decrease to almost nothing.

Comment: I think I figured out the issue - but don't have solution.  In my app, I have to play short clips in a loop - each in new thread. The volume control works if I let a clip play in infinite loop from a thread - but not if multiple threads are launched.  I may have to concat the loops in one file and launch one thread to be able to control the volume.

Comment: A `Clip` has it's own `Thread`, it does not need a new one created explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for all responses.  I solved the issue by concatenating all loops in one loop, playing it in loop and controlling the volume.  Now question is how do I mark this thread as ANSWERED? :)

Comment: It should just be a matter of selecting a check box associated with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is my assumption that once the loop starts, the volume cannot be changed, true?

No.  A `Clip` volume can be changed at any time, if it can be changed at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Andrew. Please see my notes above.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you would like real-time control over `Clip` volumes, you can make use of [AudioCue](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue). It is a small library, and was modeled as closely as I could on the `Clip` class. The volume control is guaranteed as it is done in Java rather than relying on a `FloatControl` that relies on the presence of capabilities offered by the OS and hardware, and changes are spread out on a per frame basis rather than changing only on a per-buffer boundaries.